# window.open(), browser address bar, and jQuery url decode

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I am passing values in a URL query string that are interpreted by JavaScript and used to fill out form elements.  The user click a link on one page, is taken to another page which then decodes the values from the URL and populates the form fields.

To decode the URL, I am using the [jQuery URL Decoder plugin](http://urldecoderonline.com/javascript-url-decode-jquery-plugin.htm).

This is the parameter being passed to `window.open()`:

```
http://mydomain.com/whatever?EmailAddress=me%40privacy.com&YourName=joe%20schmo&CompanyName=TEXAS%20A%20%26%20M%20-%20LUBBOCK%2C%20TX
```

When I plug that URL into the online version of the decoder, it is properly parsed - the querystring parameters are in the .params object, properly decoded.

However, after the link is clicked when I examine window.location.href, I get this:

```
http://mydomain.com/whatever?EmailAddress=me@privacy.com&YourName=joe%20schmo&CompanyName=TEXAS%20M%20&%20M%20-%20LUBBOCK,%20TX
```

Which comes out of the URL decoder as a giant mess (i.e. not properly decoded IMO because the input is not properly encoded).

How do I (safely) get back to string that's properly interpreted by the URL decoder?

Comment: Have you tried using the built-in `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a javascript function like this:

```
function urlencode(str) {
return escape(str)
      .replace(' ', '%20') // or replace with '+'
      .replace('@', '%40');
}
```

(I know you don't need the first replace but this is more complete... you can add more replaces as you need them or search for a full urlencode)

Comment: The real tricky part came with the (difficult to see) unencoded ampersand in the CompanyName parameter.